# How to manipulate users input in a functions parameter

Tags: python

I don't know if the question made sense, but I'll do my best to explain. I have many lists (rounds 1-20) and I want to ask the user what round they are on so they can jump right too it. I have a function that works with each list, I just need to know which list to use

```
round1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
round2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

class MakeUp():
    def example_round(self,filler):
        self.filler = filler
        if 'a' in filler:
            return example_function(raw_input('What round are you on?'))
```

No user is going to type round1. They're gonna type either round 1 or 1. How can I manipulate it so that whatever they input I can pull the desired round? I just want to know if there is a way to manipulate

```
example_function(raw_input('What round are you on?'))
```

so if they put 1, I can pull round1

Answer (score 0):

use dict to manage functions.

```
funcs = {"1": round1, "2": round2, ...}
funcs[input]()
```

Comment: Or, as they're numerically ordered, a list.